# Element absolute inside div relative inside display table not show element complety

Tags: html, css

I'm trying show a modal in middle of the page with a width or hight dyç

I have a div with style absolute inside div with position relative, and the button not show completely,

I try to change z-index.

link of my code https://jsfiddle.net/renatoclt/qhn9v2py/3/

Here is my HTML & CSS

```css
.ngx-utilitario-modal {
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.ngx-utilitario-modal .ngx-utilitario-modal-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.ngx-utilitario-modal .ngx-utilitario-modal-content {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.ngx-utilitario-modal .ngx-utilitario-modal-content .ngx-utilitario-modal-cerrar {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 0px;
}

.ngx-utilitario-modal-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 900;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="ngx-utilitario-modal">
  <div class="ngx-utilitario-modal-body">
    <div class="ngx-utilitario-modal-content">
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <button type="button" class="ngx-utilitario-modal-cerrar" (click)="close()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        este es ng-content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ngx-utilitario-modal-background" [@openClose]="showModal"></div>
<div class="ngx-utilitario-modal-open"></div>
```

The result actually shows half of the button. I expect to show the button completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `.ngx-utilitario-modal .ngx-utilitario-modal-content` class, you should remove `overflow-y: auto;`

Then you'll likely need to adjust the width of the modal to make it not be 100% so the close button isn't cut off on the sides.

Something like this:

```css
.ngx-utilitario-modal{
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.ngx-utilitario-modal .ngx-utilitario-modal-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.ngx-utilitario-modal .ngx-utilitario-modal-content{
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 80%;
}

.ngx-utilitario-modal .ngx-utilitario-modal-content .ngx-utilitario-modal-cerrar{
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 0px;
}

.ngx-utilitario-modal-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 900;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="ngx-utilitario-modal">
  <div class="ngx-utilitario-modal-body">
    <div class="ngx-utilitario-modal-content">
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <button type="button" class="ngx-utilitario-modal-cerrar" (click)="close()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        este es ng-content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ngx-utilitario-modal-background" [@openClose]="showModal"></div>
<div class="ngx-utilitario-modal-open"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `overflow: auto` if you want this to work. Overflow would have to be set to `visible`.